# Math in Cryptography

Tags: cryptography

I haven't been able to find a solution to what may seem to be a simple problem.

Problem: sha512(9-e) = sha512(___)

Simply, is it possible to subtract the hash string of 'e' from the hash string of '9'? Not interested in the hash of "9-e" but an actual hash string resulting from the difference.
Additionally, is it possible to subtract letters from letters, and numbers from numbers?

ie: sha512(9-5) = sha512(4)
ie: sha512(c-a) = sha512(___)

Please correct me if I'm wrong. Am unable to find any documentation on the subject.

-Thanks

Concept: I want to achieve 99.99 in sha512. Having a encrypted hash key, I'm assuming the most used letter is e (Based on the English dictionary-ignoring other characters for now).

What I'm tying to solve: sha512(___) + sha512(e) = sha512(99.99).

Comment: The whole point of cryptographically secure hash functions is, that operations like the one you want to do are impossibly difficult to do. If what you want to do were possible, it would reduce the effective entropy of the hash and make finding a preimage collision attack much easier. It would be **BAD** if that were possible.

Comment: what should it be e? a variable? a char?

Comment: @Berto99 e and 99 are given. they are the sha512 of those values. Just didn't include because it would take up most of the page. Looking for the difference of those sha512 hashes if possible.

Comment: @datenwolf  haha perhaps that is why I haven't been able to find a solution. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @Williamct: Note that it is perfectly possible to calculate `sha512(e)-sha512(99)`, after all the output of sha512 is (as the name implies) a 512 bit integer. However the whole purpose of such hash functions is, that e.g. a difference like that still has the most entropy possible and is maximally uncorrelated to the values that went into the hash function. – of course weaknesses exist and MD4, MD5 and SHA1 all have been found to have some. I.e. if you find a way to calculate what you want it would be a **MAJOR** cryptologic discovery.

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk datenwolf provided me enough info to do more research.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk datenwolf provided me enough info to do more research. Complete Concept If Your'e Interested: I am trying to calculate the chances of getting 99.9% as a reward percentage for a certain online game that uses sha512 for their algorithm. the Formula I decided to start with is sha512(__) + sha512(e) = sha512(99.9). I am using the constant sha512(e), as 'e' is the most used letter in the English language. As the hash for e and 99.9 are constants, I simply need to solve for the difference to determine the rest of the algorithm. sha512(99.9) - sha512(e) = remainder of algorithm.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with programming, and belongs on [crypto.se] instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of cryptographically secure hash functions is, that operations like the one you want to do are impossibly difficult to do. If what you want to do were possible, it would reduce the effective entropy of the hash and make finding a preimage collision attack much easier. It would be BAD if that were possible.

The thing closest to what you want to do, would fall into the realm of [Homomorphic Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption).